# Sound Cloud Error

Tags: php, audio, soundcloud

Here is my redirect.php, i always get 
'HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request. '

php code:

```
require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

// create client object with app credentials 
$client = new Services_Soundcloud('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setAccessToken($_GET['code']);

// make an authenticated call
$current_user = json_decode($client->get('me'));
print $current_user->username;
```

Any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `clientID`, `clientSecret` and `redirectURI` arguments when initializing `new Services_Soundcloud`.

Your code should look like this:

```
index.php
<?php

// create client object with app credentials
include('Services/Soundcloud.php');
$client = new Services_Soundcloud('....', '....', 'http://my.redirect.com/url.php');
$authorizeUrl = $client->getAuthorizeUrl();

?>

<a href="<?php echo $authorizeUrl; ?>">Connect with SoundCloud</a>
```

And the redirect url:

```
<?php

require_once('Services/Soundcloud.php');

// create client object with app credentials
$client = new Services_Soundcloud('.....', '.....', 'http://my.redirect.com/url.php');

try {
    $accessToken = $client->accessToken($_GET['code']);
    try {
        $me = json_decode($client->get('me'), true);
        var_dump($me);
    } catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
        exit();
    }

} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    exit();
}

?>
```

You can get the `clientId` and `clientSecret` from the [developers page](http://soundcloud.com/you/apps)

Also you can checkout the [documentation](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#server-side) for proper examples in PHP, Python, Ruby and JS

You can check the code above on this link:
[soundcloud.itnews-bg.com/](http://soundcloud.itnews-bg.com/)

Comment: Answer updated. It appears that you also need to set the third argument `redirectURI`. Checkout the documentation.

Comment: still not work. If i comment out //$current_user = json_decode($client->get('me'));, error wont show